# How do I find the original function for the derivative $\left(\dfrac{t^4+t-2}{t-1}\right)$ as t approaches 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have this problem for math, and I cannot find the original function. The problem is as follows:

> If:
> $$f'(x) = \lim_{t\to1}\left(\frac{t^4+t-2}{t-1}\right)$$
>
> What are $f(x)$ and $a$?

(I already found a). Please provide the steps as to how you got your answer.

Comment: Please check to see if I've edited your post correctly....

Comment: Where is $a$ in the question? Am I missing something?

Comment: "What is $f(x)$" looks a little metamathematics, I think would be better to say "determine" or "find" $f(x)$, and "what is $a$" is strange too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also calculates $\lim_{t\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{t^4+t-2}{t-1}$.

$\lim_{t\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{t^4+t-2}{t-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{(t-1)(t^3+t^2+t+2)}{t-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 1} t^3+t^2+t+2=5$

You said this limit is equal to $f'(x)$, then $f'(x)=5$ for all x, therefore $f(x)=5x$.
To be more precise, $f(x)=5x + C$, where $C$ is constant.